$\lim_{\delta r,\delta \theta,\delta \phi \to0}\sum_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{x=0}^{R}r^2\delta r\delta \theta \delta \phi$
I was finding the moment of inertia of a sphere of mass $m$:
$$J={\lim_{\delta r,\delta \theta,\delta \phi \to0}\sum_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{r=0}^{R}}\frac{mr^4\delta r\delta \theta \delta \phi}{\lim_{\delta r,\delta \theta,\delta \phi \to0}\sum_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{x=0}^{R}r^2\delta r\delta \theta \delta \phi}$$
Then I started to prove that the volume of a sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ with a method that I think is correct but it gives me $\frac{4}{3}\pi^2 r^3$.
I broke down the sphere into infinitesimally small cubes with side lengths $\delta r,r\delta \theta$ and $r\delta \phi$ $\because$ the length of an arc of a circle=$r\theta$ $\therefore\delta V=r^2\delta r\delta\theta\delta\phi$
So when I evaluate:
$$\lim_{\delta r,\delta \theta,\delta \phi \to0}\sum_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\sum_{r=0}^{R}r^2\delta r\delta \theta \delta \phi=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^Rr^2drd\theta d\phi=2\pi\cdot2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{3}R^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi^2R^3$$
Perhaps I made a mistake somewhere, I don't know where the extra $\pi$ came from.


Your sum notation is very odd… also as ted highlighted, your volume and domain of integration are false

Did you mean $\sum_{r=0}$ where you wrote $\sum_{x=0}?$

Please do not use MathJax-only titles.

First, in spherical coordinates, we have $dV = r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$, assuming $\theta$ is, as usual in physics, the angle from the positive $z$-axis. Second, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, not $2\pi$. Third, the moment of inertia about an axis is obtained by integrating the square of the distance from the axis, not from the origin. So you should be integrating $(r\sin\theta)^2$, not $r^2$.
Moreover, if you're going to resort to approximating by Riemann sums, your notation is horrendous. You really need to divide the region into small "parallelepipeds" and index them with positive integers. I would prefer to just work with one small "chunk" with volume $\Delta V \approx r^2\sin\theta\,\Delta r\Delta\theta\Delta\phi$ and avoid the vague, incorrect notation. If you must, then talk about a sum of such things and the intervals over which the variables range. Most mathematicians and physicists do not write out the iterated integration as a Riemann sum, but rather think of the multiple integral as a limit (in principle) of Riemann sums and then convert to the iterated integral immediately.

But why is my method not valid? It still makes sense to do it the way I did but I get an extra factor of $\pi$. Does anyone know how I can adjust my method without using the $r^2 sin\theta$ method.

Your method has all the mistakes I outlined. The final side of your box has length $r\sin\theta\Delta\phi$, not $r\Delta\phi$. Draw a picture carefully. And your upper limit for $\theta$ is wrong. Time to stop being stubborn and actually learn to do things correctlyl.

In your method you are using strips, but I am breaking down the sphere into the smallest possible pieces. The two methods must give the same result but I am missing a $\frac{1}{\pi}$.I understand that your method is correct, but imagine I am breaking down the box that you are talking about into even smaller pieces and changing the limit for $\theta$ to $2\pi$ .Surely there isn't just one method of proving that the volume of sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$.

You're just plain wrong, and your suggestion that I'm using "strips" is also wrong. Are your $r,\theta,\phi$ not the usual spherical coordinates? Include a picture. This arguing is pointless.

Here is the picture.

Oh, so your $\theta$ is the usual math one, and so $\theta$ and $\phi$ should be switched in everything I said. Your $r\delta\theta$ is wrong, because you’ve drawn a very specific picture with $\phi=\pi/2$. Put the little box much higher up.

I see the mistake now, I was considering $\theta$ from the origin and not from the axis.
